# Unique constraint violation found Magento 2 after migration

Tags: magento, magento2.2

After the migration.

Tried rebuilding the cache and re-indexed.

The issue is with "pages"

`cms_page` and `cms_page_store` do not seem to have any issues with a missing row.

From under database tried the following

```
Under cms_page
ALTER TABLE `cms_page` DROP INDEX`CMS_PAGE_TITLE_META_KEYWORDS_META_DESCRIPTION_IDENTIFIER_CONTENT`;

ALTER TABLE `cms_page` DROP INDEX `CMS_PAGE_IDENTIFIER`;


ALTER TABLE `cms_page_store` DROP INDEX `CMS_PAGE_STORE_STORE_ID`;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After digging a lot and checking the cardinality associated with the table. I figured that `url_rewrites` table added any new value with the id of 0.

The auto-increment was off.

To edit the table, first make a note of all the associated FK. Delete the Foreign Keys in those tables.

Once the associated foreignKeys are deleted, Edit the table and set Auto Increment on `url_rewrites`

Re-define the keys.

Go to Magento CLI and reindex.

Done!

**DO NOT set foreignkey check to 0**

While there are multiple suggestions which will ask you to set foreignkey check to 0. Do not do that.
That short-cut may result in data corruption.